# Selenium last conditional fail or pass

Tags: java, selenium

Consider:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myClass']/tr[1]")) != null){
    // Passed
}
else{
    // Failed
}
```

What should I write to make pass or fail for Selenium? I can do `System.out.println("failed");`, but it still shows `Failure = 0` in the end.

Comment: How do you want to fail? Do you want an exception?

Comment: @Mobrockers I want it the end result it will give `Failures:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findElements` instead of `findElement` and check the `size`:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='myClass']/tr[1]")).size() != 0){
    //passed
}else{
    //failed
}
```

You could also catch the exception:

```
try {
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myClass']/tr[1]"));
    //passed
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
    //failed
}
```

Comment: what's the different btw if else and try catch?

Comment: It will allow you to evaluate the presence of an element in both cases, so what do you have in mind by difference?

Comment: I don't understand the usage of try catch

Comment: The `findElement` method raises an exception when the targeted element is not present. So by catching the exception, you'll know that your element is missing.

Comment: I thought I can have something like `if(condition){setFalse()}else{passed()}`;

Answer (score 0):

If you want your test to fail if some conditions weren't met, try using JUnit Assertions.

```
assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.className("myClass")).size() > 0);
```

In this case, the test will fail if no elements with class `myClass` weren't found.